# How can I understand complex sentences like this?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“There are so many inquisitive people and **institutions abounding**,” said Arobin, “that one is really forced as **a matter of convenience** these days **to assume the virtue of** an occupation **if he has it not**.”

(From [Chapter 30](https://www.shmoop.com/the-awakening/chapter-30-full-text-2.html) of *The Awakening*  by Kate Chopin.)

there is several marked bold where I don't quite make me myself structure and meaning clear,how would you translate it more a simpler version?
Also if it's for any convenient ,that would be very nice of you if you could break it apart and help me about it.

Comment: I have added attribution  (Title, author, chapter, and a link). In future please add such attribution yourself when you quote a text. See ["Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes"](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457). Thank You.

Comment: @David Siegel  oh thank you I had never noticed it at all, but the sentence I posted  is just an given example from "vocabulary.com",which is only shown as a very example for word "convenience" with nothing but only its title<< Awakening>>,I guess it must have taken a very long time to locate where the sentence is in that book, so I just came up with this.

Comment: Actually, a simple Google search on {“There are so many inquisitive people and institutions abounding,” + Awakening} gave the link I posted, which listed the chapter and page, and gave surrounding context.

Comment: It's so kind of you for telling me that,thanks again.

Comment: I think that you might be advised to read something else to practice your English skills as that is almost incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> inquisitive people and institutions abounding

"*abounding*" = "existing in or providing a great or plentiful quantity or supply" according to [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abounding)

Thus this means that there are many inquisitive people and institutions.

> as a matter of convenience

This is a ***fixed phrase** (see [Cambridge here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/example/english/matter-of-convenience)) It means something done because it is practical or convenient, with little or no deeper reason.

> assume the virtue of an occupation if he has it not.”

This is an altered quote from [*Hamlet* Act 3, Scene 4](https://www.allgreatquotes.com/hamlet-quotes-260/) In *Hamlet* it means to act properly even if one did not feel like doing so. Here it means to pretend to have a job or to be on business even if that was not true.

Overall the text:

> There are so many inquisitive people and institutions abounding,” said Arobin, “that one is really forced as a matter of convenience these days to assume the virtue of an occupation if he has it not.”

means roughly:

> There are so many people and institutions around ready to ask questions, that a person finds it a very good idea to appear to have some business.

That is, that people who seem to have no current purpose are likely to b asked questions.

Comment: oh my goodness that's harsh! anyway, it seems to me that I still have long way to come along with my english, I wonder if native speaker also find some sentences in a novel or passage that may appear a little bit hard to understand? like if they haven't been much educated or just don't like reading.

Comment: @vater herrn Some do. Indeed I, who loves to read and does it a lot, sometimes Find sentences or passages that I need to stop and think my way through. Some of the works of Gene Wolfe, for example.